# MYSQL: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble with this SQL statement

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  'id' INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
  'first_name' VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  'last_name' VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  'user_name' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  'email' VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  'password' VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  'last_access' DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  'phone' VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  'cellphone' VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  'status' ENUM('Active', 'Inactive', 'Blocked', 'Deleted', 'Newreg') DEFAULT 'Active',
  PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;
```

MySQL Workbench doesn't show any syntax error,
but when executed throws the following error

```
[2018-03-24 16:07:49] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id' INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
[2018-03-24 16:07:49] 'first_name' VARCHAR(250) NOT NUL' at line 3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'id'` is a string, not a variable name.  Omit the single quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Or replace them with backticks, like:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: Holy S***!, i'm a beginner in SQL and I didn't know that, thanks!